# How to use "like" and "not like" in SQL MSAccess for the same field?

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, sql-like

I would like to filter all the rows that are:

```
field like "*AA*" and field not like "*BB*"
```

But this is returning everything instead of showing all the rows that contains `AA` and doesn't contain `BB`.

well now it works like expected, just restarted ms access...

Sorry for my typo... :s updated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
field like "*AA*" and field not like "*BB*"
```

Comment: sorry, I've made a typo in the question, now it's updated

Answer (score 1):

What I found out is that MS Access will reject --Not Like "BB*"-- if not enclosed in PARENTHESES, unlike --Like "BB*"-- which is ok without parentheses.

I tested these on MS Access 2010 and are all valid:

1. Like "*BB*"
2. (Like "*BB*")
3. (Not Like "*BB*")

Answer (score 0):

Simply restate the target field & condition;

```
where (field like "*AA*" and field not like "*BB*")
```

Comment: sorry, I've made a typo in the question, now it's updated

Comment: Do you have other conditions, and if so are the parentheses correct? Past the whole query.

Answer (score 0):

what's the problem with:

```
field like "*AA*" and field not like "*BB*"
```

it should be working.

Could you post some example of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still extant but I'm guessing you need something like

```
((field Like "AA*") AND (field Not Like "BB*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in VBA (and not in a query) then:
   where field like "*AA*" and field not like "*BB*" then
would not work.

You'd have to use:
   where field like "*AA*" and field like "*BB*" = false then